# Refused to display 'https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: google-custom-search

1. I have a Google Custom Search result page with iframe fro showing results.
2. I decide to create new one profile, and use this new in the same context.
3. So I create profile and all I did on my site - just change search ID.
4. As a result I got

   ```
   "Refused to display 'https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."
   ```
5. Then I change my ID back to the old one and it's start to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google [stop to support iframes for the custom search result](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2641279?hl=en). So your old ID's are support iframes, as legacy support but the newly created profiles does not.